# Empty JSON objects ([{},{},..]) are written to file

Tags: c#, json, serialization, javascriptserializer

im trying to write a simple list to json.

no errors, executes fine but i get this output

```
[{},{},{}]
```

here is a snippet of my code. studentList is a list of objects of Student class.

```
    public void jsonRead()
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\JSON.txt");

        studentList= new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Student>>(json);
    }

    public void jsonWrite()
    {

            string json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(studentList);

            File.WriteAllText(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\JSON.txt", json);

    }
```

student class

```
class Student : IComparable
{
    private String regID {get;set;}   
    private String name {get;set;}      
    private String address {get;set;}      
    private String gender {get;set;}      
    private Double gpa {get;set;}

    public Student()
    {
        regID = null;
        name = null;
        address = null;
        gender = null;
        gpa = 0.0;
    }
    public Student(String regID, String name, String address, String gender, Double gpa)
    {
        this.regID = regID;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }

    public void update(String regID, String name, String address, String gender, Double gpa)
    {
        setRegId( regID);
        setName(name);
        setAddress(address);
        setGender(gender);
        setGpa(gpa);
    }
```

followed by setters and getters

Comment: the object is fine. i print the list in my code. displays everything. the json.txt has nothing in it though

Comment: oh i see,its the 2nd one

Comment: i tried what you had answered, no difference in output

Comment: Can you post what your `Student` class looks like?

Comment: What is the content of the variable "json" in jsonWrite() method? before your saving it to the file?

Comment: Are you using any Unicode characters?

Comment: @user2864740 please take a look at the Student class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the solution. dont know if its the right approach or not, but i just made all the data members public. it worked

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely the right answer! Yay! But what a *PAIN* to find! Google doesn't let you search for strings such as "[{}]".
I found that even *partial* protection will prevent the serializer from writing out the text. e.g. (in C#):

```
public String Notes {private set; get}
```

puts 'Notes' out of reach.
This is also the solution with serializing XML, not just JSON.